# How to reference nsg security rules within TFVARS from a module

Tags: terraform

**How do I go about referencing the security_rules in my TFVARS file from within app1-networking_nsgs.tf**

I will be using cicd from the get go, so all my vars are defined in TFVARS file

Any assistance would be appreciated

module-nsg-main.tf

```
resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "nsg" {
  name                = var.nsg_name
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  location            = var.location
  # tags                = var.tags

  dynamic "security_rule" {
    for_each = var.security_rules
    content {
      name                                       = lookup(security_rule.value, "name", null)
      priority                                   = lookup(security_rule.value, "priority", null)
      direction                                  = lookup(security_rule.value, "direction", null)
      access                                     = lookup(security_rule.value, "access", null)
      protocol                                   = lookup(security_rule.value, "protocol", null)
      source_port_range                          = lookup(security_rule.value, "source_port_range", null)
      source_port_ranges                         = lookup(security_rule.value, "source_port_ranges", null)
      destination_port_range                     = lookup(security_rule.value, "destination_port_range", null)
      destination_port_ranges                    = lookup(security_rule.value, "destination_port_ranges", null)
      source_address_prefix                      = lookup(security_rule.value, "source_address_prefix", null)
      source_address_prefixes                    = lookup(security_rule.value, "source_address_prefixes", null)
      destination_address_prefix                 = lookup(security_rule.value, "destination_address_prefix", null)
      destination_address_prefixes               = lookup(security_rule.value, "destination_address_prefixes", null)
      source_application_security_group_ids      = lookup(security_rule.value, "source_application_security_group_ids ", null)
      destination_application_security_group_ids = lookup(security_rule.value, "destination_application_security_group_ids ", null)
    }
  }
}
```

module-nsg-outputs.tf

```
output "nsg_id" {
  description = "The ID of the newly created Network Security Group"
  value       = azurerm_network_security_group.nsg.id
}

output "nsg_name" {
  description = "The name of the new NSG"
  value       = azurerm_network_security_group.nsg.name
}
```

module-nsg-variables.tf

```
variable "resource_group_name" {
  description = "description"
  type        = string
}

variable "nsg_name" {
  description = "description"
  type        = string
}

variable "location" {
  description = "description"
  type        = string
  # default     = "West Europe"
}

variable "security_rules" {
  description = "A list of security rules to add to the security group. Each rule should be a map of values to add. See the Readme.md file for further details."

  type = list(object({
    name                       = string
    priority                   = number
    direction                  = string
    access                     = string
    protocol                   = string
    source_port_range          = string
    destination_port_range     = string
    source_address_prefix      = string
    destination_address_prefix = string
  }))
}
```

app1-networking_nsgs.tf

```
module "nsg-app1" {
  source = "git@gitlab.com:*/*"
  #   version = "1.0.0"
  nsg_name            = "dev-nsg"
  resource_group_name = module.rg-sharegate.resource_group_name
  location            = module.rg-sharegate.location
#   tags                = local.tags

  # security_rules = [
  #   {
  #     name                       = "Inbound Rule",
  #     priority                   = "100"
  #     direction                  = "Inbound"
  #     access                     = "Allow"
  #     protocol                   = "Tcp"
  #     source_port_range          = "*"
  #     destination_port_range     = "22"
  #     source_address_prefix      = "*"
  #     destination_address_prefix = "*"
  #   }
  # ]
```

dev.tfvars

```
environment      = "non-prod"
environment_code = "d"
deployment_code  = "lxr"
location_code    = "aus"
location         = "Australia Southeast"
name_suffix      = "app1"

network_octets = "10.1"
host_octets    = ".0.0/16"
subnet_octet   = "0"
cidr_prefix    = "0/24"
dns_servers    = ["1.1.1.1", "9.9.9.9"]

  security_rules = [
    {
      name                       = "Inbound Rule",
      priority                   = "100"
      direction                  = "Inbound"
      access                     = "Allow"
      protocol                   = "Tcp"
      source_port_range          = "*"
      destination_port_range     = "22"
      source_address_prefix      = "*"
      destination_address_prefix = "*"
    }
  ]
```

terraform plan -var-file=dev.tfvars

```
╷
│ Warning: Value for undeclared variable
│ 
│ The root module does not declare a variable named "security_rules" but a value was found in file "dev.tfvars". If you meant to use this value, add a "variable" block to the
│ configuration.
│ 
│ To silence these warnings, use TF_VAR_... environment variables to provide certain "global" settings to all configurations in your organization. To reduce the verbosity of
│ these warnings, use the -compact-warnings option.
╵
╷
│ Error: Missing required argument
│ 
│   on networking_nsgs.tf line 2, in module "nsg-app1":
│    2: module "nsg-app1" {
│ 
│ The argument "security_rules" is required, but no definition was found.
```

Comment: What is wrong with the code, are there any errors?

Comment: added output of tfplan

Comment: You have defined the `security_rules` variable on the module level, it does not have a default value, and it is referenced in the `for_each` for the resource. That means you have to provide the value when calling the module. So the commented out part has to be uncommented for this to work or at least to show a more meaningful error. You could however adjust the `for_each` in the resource to make it work if that is what you want to achieve.

Comment: I removed the static security_rules values in app1-networking_nsgs.tf and added nsg_security_rules = var.nsg_security_rules. Pretty simple, thanks for your help anyway :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the static `security_rules` values in app1-networking_nsgs.tf and added:

```
nsg_security_rules = var.nsg_security_rules
```